# How do you style only the top level items in TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, hierarchicaldatatemplate

For the 2nd day I'm scouring the web and have not found a solution.
Take an element like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" Width="300">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Type}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding SubTypes}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SubType}">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I use the Material NuGet library for base styles. Now however I need to disable the hover, select, etc. on the first level items and only allow the selection/hover for the subitems.

But everything I seem to find is about styling the contents of each item or styling everything globally.

```
A <- remove selection/hover (pref single click too but that's another topic)
  A1 <- maintain original style, hover and select
  A2 <- maintain original style, hover and select
  A3 <- maintain original style, hover and select
B <- remove selection/hover (pref single click too but that's another topic)
  B1 <- maintain original style, hover and select
  B2 <- maintain original style, hover and select
  B3 <- maintain original style, hover and select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't really want each top-level item to act like a normal `TreeViewItem`.  In that case, why not move the top-level items *outside* of the `TreeView`?

Basically, you'd have an `ItemsControl` of the top-level items, where the item template acts a bit like an `Expander` containing a `TreeView` of the items underneath it.  You could style the top-level items to look however you like.

The downside would be that the trees under the top-level items would be virtualized individually, not as a whole.  That is, they would not share containers.  Unless you have a *ton* of top-level items, that probably won't be a big deal.

Example:

```
<ItemsControl xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Types}">
  <ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="3,2">
        <ContentPresenter />
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
              <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Template="{StaticResource ExpanderButtonTemplate}">
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
              </ToggleButton>
              <Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentSite" Visibility="Collapsed" />
              </Border>
            </DockPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="contentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.Resources>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SubTypes}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
          <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Type}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding SubTypes}">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SubType}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Click on one of the top-level items to expand the tree beneath it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Quite possible - i'm rather new to XAML - but would it still act as a toggle control to show/hide subitems?  

The Types contains 3x models:Type and each of those contains unknown number of SubTypes.

Comment: Sure.  I added a simple proof-of-concept for an example.

Comment: Seems like this does cover and solve both style and clik issue -  now i just need to figure out and replicate the material theme the treeview uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the `TreeView` and set properties or apply a style to your top-level items (assuming your `TreeView` isn't nested in another `TreeView`) by searching up the logical hierarchy for a `TreeViewItem`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" Value="{x:Null}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
</DataTrigger>
```

For top-level items this binding spams warnings to debug output, but they can safely be ignored. A more sophisticated version of this trick would be to create an inheritable attached property `TreeViewItemLevel` that would be set to zero on the `TreeView` and to one more than the inherited value on `TreeViewItem`s.

Answer (score 0):

While setting a `DataTrigger` with a relative source binding works, it will produce binding **errors**.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" Value="{x:Null}">
```

By setting a `FallbackValue` of `x:Null`, you will not get any binding errors, but **warnings**.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" Value="{x:Null}">
```

An alternative approach that will neither yield errors nor warnings, is to create a value converter that essentially does the same a `RelativeSource` binding, but will handle the errors, too. It returns `true` for any dependency object passed in, if it has an ancestor of type `TreeViewItem`, `false` otherwise.

```
public class IsRootTreeViewItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value is null ? Binding.DoNothing : !HasTreeViewItemAncestor((DependencyObject)value);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }

   private static bool HasTreeViewItemAncestor(DependencyObject child)
   {
      var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

      return parent switch
      {
         null => false,
         TreeViewItem _ => true,
         _ => HasTreeViewItemAncestor(parent)
      };
   }
}
```

In your `TreeViewItem` style trigger, you can use the converter by binding to the item itself with `Self`.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsRootTreeViewItemConverter}}" Value="True">
```

This approach works for both statically assigned `TreeViewItems` and `ItemsSource` bindings.