# Hiding Expand/Collapse icon in TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I use a `TreeView` to create a generic Json Object editor. However, I want to hide the expand/collapse icons completely. I have searched a lot, but couldn't find any working solution so far. Is there a simple way to override the appropriated style to get rid of the collapse/expand functionality?

```
<TreeView Name="m_TreeView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Any ideas how to achive that without creating a complete new `TreeViewItem` template?

Comment: The icon is a checkbox that is the control to expand / collapse a treeview item.  if this is removed, you cannot expand / collapse treeview items.  In this case, use a listbox or listview.  However, if you want to keep as a treeview, have VS convert the default "ItemContainerStyle"  to a local resource and remove the toggle button.

Comment: I want the treeview to no be able to collapse/expand at all. Do you have an example for the removing of the toggle button throw ItemContainerStyle change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collapse / expand `ToggleButton` is defined in the control template of the `TreeViewItem` and there are not any properties to hide them. Consequently, you have to adapt the `TreeViewItem` template.

You can create a copy of the default `TreeViewItem` style [using Visual Studio or Blend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio) and adapt it. The key is to remove the `Expander` `ToggleButton` and its triggers. The column for it must be kept for the indentation. The setter for the `IsExpanded` property expands all items by default.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
           Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Background"
           Value="Transparent" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
           Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
           Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
   <Setter Property="Padding"
           Value="1,0,0,0" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground"
           Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                     <Rectangle />
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
               <local:DataTypeConverter x:Key="DataTypeConverter" />
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                    MinWidth="0" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition />
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Border x:Name="Bd"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                       BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
               </Border>
               <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                        Value="false">
                  <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                          Property="Visibility"
                          Value="Collapsed" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                          Property="Background"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                  <Setter Property="Foreground"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
               </Trigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                Value="true" />
                     <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive"
                                Value="false" />
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                          Property="Background"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}" />
                  <Setter Property="Foreground"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
               </MultiTrigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing"
               Value="true">
         <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <VirtualizingStackPanel />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you want to remove the indentation of the root level items, you can refer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548807/how-do-you-style-only-the-top-level-items-in-treeview).

[image: TreeView with first level indentation.]

Comment: Sorry the indentation removing doesn't work, the rest is working. The DataTypeConverter is called, but the value passed in is always null. Any idea what going wrong?

Comment: @Lori Are there any binding errors in the output? Could you try to replace the trigger with `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">` just for testing purposes?

Comment: I have no binding errors shown in the VS 2019 when starting. If I replace the trigger with what you mentioned, than all identation are gone (as expected).

Comment: I got it working. I use custom TreeNode types for each item in my Tree. After changing the DataTrigger to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource DataTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type tree:TreeNode}">` and the Convert Logic to be aware of resolving the Header of the passed in TreeViewItem and check there if a Parent is present or not.

Comment: @Lori The sample that I showed only works for statically created `TreeViewItem`s, not for items bound by `ItemsSource` I figured out. However, I have added a link to a related question that focuses on styling top level items. You can either use the approach of splitting the `TreeView` using `ItemsControl` or use the data trigger solutions that you can directly integrate into control template or style.